# How do I fetch a different url from a page in java?

Tags: java

I am working on a program to download the first 100 comics from the **XKCD** website, however the URL for XKCD differs from the image url. For the sake of ease, I was wondering if there was a simple way to grab the URL for the image after going to the XKCD URL. Here is my code:

```
public class XKCD {

public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, int i) throws IOException {
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
String fileName = url.getFile();
String destName = i + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/"));
System.out.println(destName);

InputStream is = url.openStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destName);

byte[] b = new byte[2048];
int length;

while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
    os.write(b, 0, length);
}

is.close();
os.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, 
IOException {
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
        saveImage("https://xkcd.com/"+i+"/", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't this is clear enough... what do you want to do exactly? how's the urls differ?

Comment: the urls are incrimental, for example: https://xkcd.com/100 https://xkcd.com/101

Answer (score 1):

XKCD Has a JSON API:  https://xkcd.com/about/

> Is there an interface for automated systems to access comics and metadata?
>   Yes. You can get comics through the JSON interface, at URLs like http://xkcd.com/info.0.json (current comic) and http://xkcd.com/614/info.0.json (comic #614).

Here is a good java JSON library: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

REALLY easy to use, I have used it a lot.

So if you have the text from xkcd.com/info.0.json in txt, you say:

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(txt);
String url=obj.getString("img");
String titleText=obj.getString("alt");
int year=Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("year"));
int num=Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("num"));
int month=Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("month"));
int day=Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("day"));
String title=obj.getString("title");

Image img=downloadImageOrWhateverYouDoWithTheImageURL(url);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) for that. It can produce an absolute URL from a relative link:

You can import the library into your project using:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And you can get the absolute path of the image using simply code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://xkcd.com/").get();
    Elements links = document.select("img");
    links.stream()
            .map(link -> link.absUrl("src"))
            .filter(str -> str.contains("/comics"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you run this code you will see the image URL printed out on the console:

```
https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/river_border.png
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that you're calling saveImage method not with image, but page URL.

Get the page itself, then parse regex from such example string :

```
"Image URL (for hotlinking/embedding): https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/barrel_cropped_(1).jpg"
```

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a regex, get a HTML Parser.